VideoView Control From LibVlcSharp does not resize within the grid
Player is always invisible. It is not resizing itself according to grid row. libvlcsharp When I give it Height and Width property it is working no invisible anymore, but I don't want that way because my window is resizable and want player to grow with window.
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged" CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">


        <Grid x:Name="GridSide" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"   >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="750"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="800"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <wpf1:VideoView   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent"  Visibility="Collapsed"  x:Name="TrailerPlayer" ></wpf1:VideoView>

  <Grid x:Name="MainMovieTvShow" Background="#000000" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
</Grid>

       </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>

await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
     DispatcherPriority.Background,
     new Action(() =>
     {
         TrailerPlayer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         MainMovieTvShow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
         var rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
         rowDefinition.Height = new GridLength(1.3, GridUnitType.Star);
         GridSide.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(0);
         GridSide.RowDefinitions.Insert(0, rowDefinition);

         

     }));

I tried
TrailerPlayer.Height = GridSide.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight;

 <Grid x:Name="GridPlayer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
     <wpf1:VideoView Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=GridPlayer}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=GridPlayer}" Background="Transparent"  Visibility="Collapsed"  x:Name="TrailerPlayer" ></wpf1:VideoView>
 </Grid>

